# What's the first licensed Skill-Deck Building World / LitRPG?

Tags: history-of, litrpg

Like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/litrpg/comments/10z1zo6/deckbuilding_litrpg_is_this_a_thing_ive_just/) reddit thread, finding "All The Skills" has made me think about the origins of the Deckbuilding genre.

[Amazon's Kindle books on Deckbuilding](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Deckbuilding&i=digital-text) show that [Goblin Summoner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B091HGBYS7) seems to be the oldest one on there.

I'm looking for the oldest story with many many cards spread out throughout the world, with LitRPG-ish skills stored in them. "Older" stories like Goblin Summoner is more like a Trading Card Game, with monsters stored in them, like *Yu-Gi-Oh* and *Magic: The Gathering*.

That thread mentions [World Keeper](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/7509/world-keeper) which is from 7/16/2016, but what type of card system it has, I don't know. Sounds like "Spells stored in cards" instead of skills *or* monsters.

> World Keeper has a version of deck built magic, but not right away. It is one of many magic systems.

---

I want to find the earliest story that has:

1. Cards that give skills (Skill Cards) that are dependent on possessing the card.
2. The protagonist wants to get many / all the cards.
3. There's enough that possibly everyone in the world can have one? Or at least a significant fraction, like 1/100 or something, just not something like there being only one magical deck of 52 cards, for the world population of 8+ Billion or whatever their world's population is.

Comment: I'm not certain if I know the scope of your question. Do you require the traditional LitRPG setup where the characters (or at least certain ones) are aware of their stats? Does it require someone having designed that system? As it is, it feels like a number of Vancian works fit this since spellbooks/scrolls are essentially collectable cards.

Comment: Is is your objection to *Card Captor Sakura* that the number of cards is constrained? Is too few for your liking? That they're somewhat self-aware?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - My objection to *Card Captor Sakura Fanfic* **was** that the "skill cards" idea is not as "original" as if it were an independent licensed work, and finding it unlikely that the genre sprung up from there, but if the idea did come from there, then it did. Changing my parameters.